# oracle insufficient priviliges when creating view using a procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, view, procedure, create-view

When calling a procedure which should create a view, it returns "Insufficient Privileges". I can create the view using the SQL command itself, but not when running the procedure. All actions done are in the schema owner. Please let me know how to solve this issue.

```
/* 1. FIRST, I LOGON TO MY OWN SCHEMA, CALLED 'MY_SCHEMA' */
/* (IF YOU WANT TO USE A DIFFERENT ONE, JUST REPLACE THE TEXT MY_SCHEMA WITH YOUR OWN SCHEMA NAME) */

/* 2. DROP THE EXAMPLE TABLE IF IT ALREADY EXISTS */
DECLARE TBL_COUNT INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO TBL_COUNT FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'MY_SCHEMA' AND TABLE_NAME = 'EXAMPLE';
  IF TBL_COUNT > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('DROP TABLE "MY_SCHEMA"."EXAMPLE"');
  END IF;
END;
/
-- Result : Done

/* 2. CREATE THE EXAMPLE TABLE */
CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE
(
  COL1 INTEGER
);
-- Result : Done 

/* 3. THEN, CREATE A VIEW IN MY OWN SCHEMA, WHICH POINTS TO THE TABLE IN MY OWN SCHEMA */
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_SCHEMA.VW_EXAMPLE AS SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE;
-- Result : Done 

/* 4. DROP THE VIEW, JUST FOR ARGUMENT'S SAKE */
DROP VIEW MY_SCHEMA.VW_EXAMPLE;
-- Result : Done 

/* 5. NOW CREATE A PROCEDURE IN MY OWN SCHEMA, WHICH CREATES A VIEW IN MY OWN SCHEMA, WHICH POINTS TO A TABLE IN MY OWN SCHEMA */
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_SCHEMA.PRC_EXAMPLE AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_SCHEMA.VW_EXAMPLE AS SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.EXAMPLE';
END;
-- Done

/* 6. LET'S CALL THE PROCEDURE FROM MY OWN SCHEMA, WHICH SHOULD CREATE THE VIEW IN MY OWN SCHEMA, POINTING TO A TABLE IN MY OWN SCHMEA */
BEGIN
  MY_SCHEMA.PRC_EXAMPLE;
END;
-- ORA-01031 : Insufficient privileges
```

Comment: Are your DDL privileges granted through a role, rather than directly to your user? Why do you want to create objects atr untime anyway - the schema should normally be maintained statically.

Answer (score 0):

What are the privileges of user MY_SCHEMA?

Inside a procedure (or PL/SQL block) only **directly granted** privileges apply. Privileges granted by role (e.g. role `DBA` or `RESOURCE`) do not apply inside a procedure or PL/SQL Block.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, even though the procedure is created in MY_SCHEMA by MY_SCHEMA, and applies only to objects in MY_SCHEMA, more priviliges need to be set? To which objects or for what actions do I need to set priviliges? And how can I set these priviliges?

Comment: You need privilege `CREATE VIEW`. You get it by `GRANT CREATE VIEW TO MY_SCHEMA;`

Comment: From which schema can I grant this privilige? When I execute the     GRANT CREATE VIEW TO MY_SCHEMA; in my schema, it also says Insufficient Priviliges.

Comment: Ask your DBA to grant it.